# Trying to speed up SQL queries that slow when combined

Tags: sql-server

I have a test database with 30 million records. 60,000 have the 'Collection' value 'THIS'. When doing the queries seperately I get the times shown below, however combining them results in an increase in the query times.

When I search using the SQL query:

```
SELECT RecordId FROM Records WHERE [Collection] = 'THIS'
TIME: 14ms

SELECT RecordId FROM Records WHERE CONTAINS(Tags, '"CAT" AND "SAT" AND "MATT"')
TIME: 140ms

SELECT RecordId FROM Records WHERE CONTAINS(Tags, '"CAT" AND "SAT" AND "MATT"') AND [Collection] = 'THIS'
TIME: 250ms
```

Is there any way to combine the queries without getting the slowdown in performance? To get the times shown I have Full Text Search enabled and Indexing enabled.

Comment: Obviously the full text and ordinary indexes are confusing each other. Run them with execution plan on and see what the difference is there.

Comment: You'd probably benefit from moving the tags out of your records table and adding them to a Tag and RecordTag (lookup) table

Comment: Thanks very much but I tried it as a seperate table that looked up the values and it resulted in times that were in minutes to return large queries. I had indexed the Tags table when i had it. At the moment 250ms is pretty good but I want to make it better